# How to run a Rspec scenario with multiple tags?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, ui-automation, site-prism

I am using ruby client for web automation with selenium. I am running them parallel using parallel_rspec. I want to run the tests which has `smoke` and `ae` tags set.

My scenarios looks like:

```rb
scenario 'Test1', :smoke, :regression, :ae do
  "do something"
end

scenario 'Test2', :smoke, :bh do
  "do something"
end

scenario 'Test3', :smoke, :ae, :bh do
  "do something"
end
```

I am executing them like:

```
parallel_rspec spec/**/*_spec.rb -o '--tag smoke --tag ae --format progress --format ParallelTests::RSpec::RuntimeLogger --out tmp/parallel_runtime_rspec.log -f json -o tmp/AE/run$TEST_ENV_NUMBER.json' -n 3
```

But I found it does not pick the right candidates for run Test1 and Test3. my goal is to run only the tests which has tag smoke and ae.

Please suggest if you have done something similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the propositional logic which combines the two (AND). In most runners this the space character as you've put.

Try just running `rspec . --tag smoke --tag ae and then go from there with your debugging.